# next view controller is not appearing when i launched apps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I am getting  `NSLog` message when  i am runing apps but `nextviewcontroller`(welcome page)is not appearing, i want to call  `nextviewcontroller` first time that have a action continue .this screen will  appear first time only when we run first time. Condition is working but `nextviewcontroller` is not coming .I used this code so for

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{ 

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Configure logging framework

[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

// Setup the XMPP stream

[self setupStream];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
BOOL launch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];

if(!launch){
    NSLog(@"first");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    self.viewController1 = [[welcomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
}
else{

    NSLog(@"second");
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;


}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if (![self connect])
{
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //messageTableViewController
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        //[navigationController presentModalViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
    });
}
return YES;
```

Comment: where is your window??is it an outlet or you are using storyboard?

Comment: everytime you got the NSLog as "first"?

Comment: I guess [self connect] is returning false first time and your dispatch_after code is running and hence you are not seeing the welcome page.

Comment: @ what i need to do  solve this

Comment: What is inside your [self connect] logic? Change it. You dont need to run the if-block first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using story boards and if your window is not an IBOutlet do this.

```
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 //add this
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

BOOL launch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
if(!launch){
    NSLog(@"first");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
    self.viewController1 = [[welcomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
}
else{

    NSLog(@"second");
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;


}
```

Comment: self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; i have this line in my code the after also is not coming

Comment: but in output window i am getting TradeSender[65134:c07] first this message ,when i am runnig but not screen

Comment: can you set some background color to your view controller and test whether you see something?

Comment: yes used this same code in sample project but it is not working

Comment: is your view controller all right?? I mean does it have all the outlets properly wired?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UIStoryBoard` , Then try with this

```
`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` .: application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {    
         BOOL launch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
                if(!launch){
                    NSLog(@"first");
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
                    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_ID"];

                    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
                }
                else{

                    NSLog(@"second");
                    self.viewController = // Follow the above
                    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;    
                }
```

If you are not working with the Storyboard then please describe your problem briefly` ,.

Comment: i am not using storyborad,i used xib for both first and second controller

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL launch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
    if(!launch){
        NSLog(@"first");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"LaunchingFirstTime"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.viewController1 = [[welcomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"welcomePage" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"second");
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `synchronize` method to make the user defaults get written on disk immediately.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

From Apple Docs:

```
synchronize method writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.
```

It is missing in your code. Write it in `if` clause.

Comment: my condition is working i think ,because  when i am runing first time then nslog message is coming in output window but screen first(wecome page) in not coming

Comment: Did you try to debug? that will tell you the exact flow your app is taking.

Comment: if(!launch){
       
        
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: then also second screen came first time

Comment: Write synchronize method after you have set the LaunchingFirstTime key. Also, try debugging and please post the complete didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: i posted my full code on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method